# Woocommerce 'My orders' add/remove column

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

In the Woocommerce customer account, I'd like to remove the following columns:

- Order number
- Order total

And add a column to display attached files (thanks to the WooCommerce Attach Me! plugin). The developer gave me this information:

> "To get all the order attachments use the following snippet:"

`global  $wcam_order_model;
$order_attachments = $wcam_order_model->get_attachments_metadata($order_id , array());`

> Where $order_id is the order id for which you want to retreive attachments. Then to get each attachment title use the following shippet:

`foreach($order_attachments as $order_attachment)
$file_name = basename($order_attachment['absolute_path']);`

I have found a tutorial here: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/adding-columns-woocommerce-orders-list/

But I can't get it work. As you imagine, I am not a developer :/

Thank you very much!

Comment: Honestly, I'd recommending getting Admin Columns Pro. You can customize any of your columns in the site.

Comment: I meant, on the frontend, in the customer account

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your functions.php

```
function sv_wc_add_my_account_orders_column( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array();
    foreach ( $columns as $key => $name ) {

        if( 'order-number' === $key || 'order-total' === $key ) {
            echo ' name '.$name . ' key ' . $key ;
            continue;
        }

        $new_columns[ $key ] = $name;

        /*if( 'order-date' === $key) {
            $new_columns['order-number'] = __( 'Order', 'textdomain' );
            $new_columns['order-rental-period'] = __( 'Rental Period', 'textdomain' );
            $new_columns['order-detail'] = __( 'Order or Quotation Detail', 'textdomain' );
         }*/

    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'sv_wc_add_my_account_orders_column' );

    return $new_columns;

}
```

Comment: } add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'sv_wc_add_my_account_orders_column' );                                                                                  this line should also be in your code put it below return $new_columns;